# React useState hook state updater function error: useNameOfFunction is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm using React's useState:

```
  const [data, setData] = ([]);
```

and it keeps giving me the error that the setState (in this case setData) is not a function

I wanted to add this here so others can save the many hours it took me to figure out my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The state wasn't being initialized properly.
What I did wrong:

```
  const [data, setData] = ([]);
```

How I fixed it:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```